# installing mysqldb for flask ERROR [OSX]

Tags: python, macos, flask, mysql-python

1. macOS 10.13.2
2. Python 2.7.14

Hi all! I'm currently working on a website made in python (flask), but I'm experiencing an issue when I try to install MYSQLDB for python. I want to use it for my database where I can store users and other data. First of all, here is the terminal output when I input:

> **pip install flask-mysqldb**

```
    Collecting flask-mysqldb
  Using cached Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/b3/4tr2p1w10cx70rqpqh28m30r0000gn/T/pip-build-4sX19x/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b3/4tr2p1w10cx70rqpqh28m30r0000gn/T/pip-build-4sX19x/mysqlclient/
```

This error message doesn't help me at all, I don't know what to do with it. After getting the error I searched for a solution on different sites, but none of the solutions is working for me. Here are some 'solutions' I tried

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome.git
```

---

```
sudo -H pip3 install gitsome
```

---

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

---

When I input:

> **sudo -H pip install flask-mysqldb**

This is the output:

```
Collecting flask-mysqldb
  Downloading Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 556kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-P4Y1ub/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-P4Y1ub/mysqlclient/
```

I would really appreciate any help to resolve this problem! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, is it required to use Flask-MySQLdb? I have another option, but I need to confirm before suggesting it to you. :)

Comment: thx for your response! I was thinking to use sqlite but I can't figger out how to implement it into my site ;) 
Im open for suggestions so just shoot!

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion below? @vincent-van-minnebruggen

Comment: not yet @fábio-correia, I'm currently working on different websites and I will continue the python site at the end of this week! I was trying to use sqlite3 before, but didn't get it to work yet... Thanks for the suggestion already, I'll see what I can do with it and let you know if I could fix my problem with it ;)

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is to manipulate the DB, I will recommend using [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/) and [right here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/#connection-uri-format) you will find how to connect using MySQL databases.

Flask-SQLAlchemy is a ORM (Object Relational Mapper) so, you will probably have to code map the DB

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! Although I didn't use it, I really appreciate your help.
I fixed it by using sqlite3, I like this solution because I could use the DB Browser with it.